# Rails 3.1 - Cant edit and create on same partial - nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a admin section and inside the admin i have, Finalist and Images.
Im using, ruby 1.8.7-p249 and Rails 3.1.2

```
# model image.rb
class Admin::Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :finalist
    ...
end

# model finalist.rb
class Admin::Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :images
    ...
end
```

My ImagesController:

```
def new
  @admin_finalist = Admin::Finalist.find(params[:finalist_id])
  @admin_image = @admin_finalist.images.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @admin_image }
  end
end

def edit
  @admin_finalist = Admin::Finalist.find(params[:finalist_id])
  @admin_image = @admin_finalist.images.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @admin_finalist = Admin::Finalist.find(params[:finalist_id])
  @admin_image = @admin_finalist.images.new(params[:admin_image])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @admin_image.save
      format.html { redirect_to admin_finalist_images_path(@admin_finalist) }
      format.json { render :json => @admin_image, :status => :created, :location => @admin_image }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.json { render :json => @admin_image.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  @admin_finalist = Admin::Finalist.find(params[:finalist_id])
  @admin_image = @admin_finalist.images.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @admin_image.update_attributes(params[:admin_image])
      format.html { redirect_to admin_finalist_images_path(@admin_finalist) }
      format.json { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.json { render :json => @admin_image.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And my Images _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for([@admin_finalist, @admin_image]) do |f| %>
    <% if @admin_image.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@admin_image.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this admin_image from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
            <% @admin_image.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :file %>
        <%= f.file_field :file %>
    </div>
    <%- unless @admin_image.new_record? || !@admin_image.file? -%>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :remove_file, "Remover?" %>
        <%= f.check_box :remove_file %>
    </div>
    <%- end -%>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :url %>
        <%= f.text_field :url, :placeholder => "http://" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= image_submit_tag("button/save.png") %>
        <%= link_to image_tag("button/back.png"), admin_finalist_images_path %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Everything seems perfect, but im getting this error when im trying to add an image to finalist at **admin/finalists/1/images/new**.

```
Showing .../app/views/admin/images/_form.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `admin_finalist_admin_images_path' for #<#<Class:0x102da0068>:0x102d9a870>
```

So, i tryed to tell rails to use a particular url:

```
<%= form_for([@admin_finalist, @admin_image], :url => admin_finalist_image_path(@admin_finalist.id, @admin_image)) do |f| %>
```

Saddly, this work only for editing. When i try to edit i get this error message:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"admin/images", :finalist_id=>1, :id=>nil, :action=>"show"}
```

And if i wanna create i need to do:

```
<%= form_for([@admin_finalist, @admin_image], :url => admin_finalist_images_path) do |f| %>
```

And if i try to edit i get this message:

```
No route matches [PUT] "/admin/finalists/1/images"
```

I dont know what to do... I tried everything without success, if anyone can help me would be much appreciated.

## EDIT

The problem was that my models was namespaced. So, i rewrite all the app to fix this, and thats running normally.

[]`s

Comment: open a command line and go to your project directory and try this `rake routes | grep finalist`. This will return you all the routes involving finalist. Choose the one you need .( Ihope you are on Linux)

Comment: @Octopus-Paul im on a Mac! :) Which one i need to use to edit and create a new image for finalist?

Comment: OK if you're on a Mac, the command that I suggested will work, run it and see which one of the printed route is the one you need. Did you define you're image routes as a nested resources under finalist?

Comment: Yes, i do! resources :finalists do resources :images end.The problems become when i need to PUT and POST, which the PUT need an image id, and POST not...

Comment: Why  is your model namespaced? I don't think it should be, as this should be precisely the same model that is used for the admin and non-admin views of your site.

Comment: Yes, i think thats the problem... i just generate de standar scaffold Admin::Finalist and Admin::Images. Im changing all models, right now.

Comment: Do you have something like `edit_finalists_images_path` ? From what you describe above you're path should look similar.

Comment: @Octopus-Paul, i dont have this route, but i tried. All routes are singular, except, admin_finalist_images.